# Why is this happening? (memory lose(?))

Tags: c, gdb

I can't seem t find why my program is crashing with segmentation fault.

```
char *nom;
char **tmp=&nom;

printf("Creando ruta ...\n");
printf("\nIntrodueix el id de la ruta: ");
int ID=demanaInt();
int existe=checkIfRutaExisteix(ID);
if(existe==1){
    printf("Ja existeix una ruta amb aquesta ID (id ha de ser unica)");
    return;
}

printf("\nIntrodueix el nom de la ruta: ");
demanaString(tmp);
    
printf("\nIntrodueix el numero de parades: ");
int numParades=demanaInt();
Ruta *r = malloc(sizeof(*r) + sizeof(Parades) + sizeof(*(r->parades.coordenades)) * numParades + sizeof(nom));
strcpy(r->nom, nom);

if(numParades!=-1){
    r->parades.numParades=numParades;
}else{
    return;
}
int c;
for(int i=0;i<numParades;i++){
    r->parades.coordenades[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(r->parades.coordenades[i])*2));
    printf("Introdueix la coordenada x de la parada numero %d: ", i);
    c=demanaInt();
    if(c==-1){
        return;
    }
    r->parades.coordenades[i][0]=c;
    printf("Introdueix la coordenada y de la parada numero %d: ", i);
    c=demanaInt();
    if(c==-1){
        return;
    }
    r->parades.coordenades[i][1]=c;
    printf("%d, %d\n", r->parades.coordenades[i][0], r->parades.coordenades[i][1]);
}

printf("Introdueix ID regio: ");
r->IDregio=demanaInt();
r->ID=ID;
guardaRutaCSV(r);
```

Just before asking for an int evreything is correct, but after that I seem to lose information.

This is my output of GDB:

```
Creando ruta ...

Introdueix el id de la ruta: 4

Introdueix el nom de la ruta: ref

Introdueix el numero de parades: 3
Introdueix la coordenada x de la parada numero 0: 1
Introdueix la coordenada y de la parada numero 0: 2
1, 2
Introdueix la coordenada x de la parada numero 1: 3
Introdueix la coordenada y de la parada numero 1: 4
3, 4
Introdueix la coordenada x de la parada numero 2: 5
Introdueix la coordenada y de la parada numero 2: 6
5, 6

Breakpoint 1, generarRuta () at ruta.c:90

90          printf("Introdueix ID regio: ");

(gdb) p r->parades.coordenades[0][1]

$1 = 2

(gdb) n

91          r->IDregio=demanaInt();

(gdb) p r->parades.coordenades[0][1]

$2 = 2

(gdb) n

Introdueix ID regio: 99

92          r->ID=ID;

(gdb) p r->parades.coordenades[0][1]

No se puede acceder a la memoria en la dirección 0x555500000067
```

Why is no longer accesible the information inside the array?

PD: here is the struct:

```c
typedef struct _parades{
    int numParades;
    int *coordenades[];
} Parades;

typedef struct _ruta{
    int ID;
    Parades parades;
    int IDregio;
    char nom[];
} Ruta;
```

Comment: You have a `*2` inside the `sizeof`, which can't be right. There are possibly other issues but you need to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A struct with a flexible array member (array with `[]`) can't be used as a member in another struct.  From the C spec (6.7.2.1):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
> a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
> of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
> recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
> element of an array.

The `shall` here indicates that the compiler *should* be giving you a diagnostic message for this code.  (`Parades` being such a structure means it can't be used as a member in `Ruta`)